# How to make this simple figure to an SVG xml path?

Tags: xml, svg, vector-graphics

In the last two days I'm trying to recreate this icon into an svg which I got only as an image. I'm really new to SVG coding.

[image: Figure]

I tried to code it, but this is all what I got:

`<svg width="100" height="100"><path d="M50 0, L 100 100, L 50 85, L 0 100, Z"/></svg>`

Maybe you can help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try this d attribute instead: ` d="M40.609,18.783 Q50,0 59.391,18.783L90.609,81.217 Q100,100 79.886,93.966L50,85L20.114,93.966 Q0,100 9.391,81.217Z"`

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and draw whatever you want.

Comment: SVG is XML format and can be very complicated.  Images can contain many layers.  Layers can contain link to images like JPG and GIF.  Where is you icon?  It looks like you created a layer with not image in the layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments (and you started doing yourself) you can use a path element. And you probably need an editor for drawing it.

The alternative that I suggest here is to "construct" the shape using different basic elements (here lines) to create a mask. Its more code, but easier to modify.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1" stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-width="12" stroke="white">
      <g transform="translate(50 30)">
        <line x2="40" transform="rotate(115)" />
        <line x2="40" transform="rotate(65)" />
        <line y2="30" />
      </g>
      <line transform="translate(50 30) rotate(65)
        translate(40 0) rotate(130)" x2="30" />
      <line transform="translate(50 30) rotate(115)
        translate(40 0) rotate(-130)" x2="30"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="black"/>
  <rect mask="url(#m1)" width="100" height="100"
    fill="white"/>
</svg>
```